# Top route destinations for a city using google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes, gps, maps

I'm looking for data on the most used route destinations for a city or an area on google maps. Ideally for a specified time interval (I'm to optimistic here aren't I).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google Places API Web Service which allows you to query for place information depending on how a specific destination or route is prominent.

Making use of the google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE parameter can return ranked results of prominent places. The prominence however will be affected by different factors such as place's ranking in Google's index, global popularity, etc.